backspacing on value (esp at beginning) throws off all the values in cell - how to correct?
I have columns I want to be able to select several values from a dropdown. The issue is when I select 2 values from the dropdown and try to 'manually backspace' on the first value (to remove it) - it instead removes the second value, and keeps the first. If I have more than 2 values, and try to remove the first value, my sheet will throw a Stop Error (this - I am ok with - but if there's a more elegant solution to accomplish my goals - please propose it).
E.g., Carrot, Eggs ... If I remove Carrot, the list will then show Carrot ... when in fact it should be Eggs. If it's Carrot, Eggs, Celery and I remove Carrot ... I will get Eggs, Celery (which is correct).
I use Data Validation/List/Stop Alerts on the columns with multiple dropdown selection capability. This is possible due to my creating 'Names' with 'Define Name' to use.
Another thing - any way to remove warning symbols from the multi selection dropdown columns when selecting multiple values? The warning symbol has a dropdown to select actions to take (Data validation error, Display Type Information, Help on This Error, etc.) - can I remove these warnings - or should I allow them? It doesn't seem to disrupt the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish?
My code:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Const SEPARATOR As String = "/ "
   Dim Oldvalue As String
   Dim Newvalue As String
   On Error GoTo Exitsub
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C, D:D, E:E, G:G")) Is Nothing Then
      If Not Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
         If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
               Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
               If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                  Target.Value = Oldvalue & SEPARATOR & Newvalue
               Else
                  Dim parts() As String
                  parts = Split(Oldvalue, SEPARATOR)
                  Dim n As Long
                  For n = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
                     If parts(n) = Newvalue Then
                        parts(n) = "|#|"
                        Exit For
                     End If
                  Next n
                  Target.Value = Join(Filter(parts, "|#|", False), SEPARATOR)
               End If
            End If
         End If
      End If
   End If
Exitsub:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


You might need to reconsider the logic. For example, if the target cell contains "Carrot, Eggs," and the user removes "Carrot," the expected result should be "Eggs." Similarly, if the user selects "Eggs" from a dropdown list, the expected result should be "Carrot, Eggs."(no duplicated Eggs) In both scenarios, the Target argument has the same value (Eggs). The Change event cannot determine the user's action.
